# substring with calculated end position

Tags: macros, strings, parameters, stringstrings

I have a string and I would like to use only the first part of the string up to a specific position. So I wrote the \stringpart command using strinstrings' functions.

The position of the searched word (--) where I want to split is found without issues. But when I want to use that position in the \substring command it gives me errors.

I am stuck -- can someone please help here? -- Thanks a lot!

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand\stringpart[1]{
        input: #1\\
        string end is at position\ \whereisword{#1}{--}\\% this works
        \substring{#1}{1}{\whereisword[q]{#1}{--}}\\% this gives errors
}

\begin{document}
\stringpart{this -- that}
\end{document}
```

Errors:

```
! Use of \\isnextbyte doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.11 \stringpart{this -- that}
! Use of \\whereisword doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...d@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.11 \stringpart{this -- that}
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal 
                  {\@@teststring }{\endofstring }
l.11 \stringpart{this -- that}
! Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 \stringpart{this -- that}
[... and more errors]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the place where the splitting takes place, you can use `expl3` features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\stringpart}{O{1}mO{--}}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mayr_string_seq { #3 } { #2 }
  \seq_item:Nn \l_mayr_string_seq { #1 }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_mayr_string_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X\stringpart{this -- that}X

X\stringpart[2]{this -- that}X

X\stringpart{this;that}[;]X

X\stringpart[2]{this;that}[;]X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`stringstrings` isn't the best package (I can say that, since I wrote it).  In this case, though, the `\substring` macro wants to see an actual value, not a macro as its end-location argument. I should rewrite that piece of code to make it more forgiving.  In the meantime, one needs to expand `\theresult`, which contains the intermediate calculation of the `\whereisword`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcommand\stringpart[1]{
        input: #1\\
        string end is at position\ \whereisword{#1}{--}\\% this works
        \whereisword[q]{#1}{--}% REDUNDANT, UNLESS ABOVE LINE IS REMOVED
        \def\tmp{\substring{#1}{1}}%
        \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\theresult}\\% this gives errors
}

\begin{document}
\stringpart{this -- that}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted to be able to operate with expandable arguments in slots `#3` and `#4` of `\substring`, one can use this formulated `\Substring` macro.  Note though, that while `\theresult` expands to a number, `\whereisword` is not an expandable argument (it only produces an expandable output in `\theresult`).

In the MWE below, I actually pass `\the\numexpr\theresult-1\relax` as argument `#4` to `\Substring` to show that it can handle something more complex, as long as it is expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand\Substring[4][v]{%
  \edef\tmpA{#3}%
  \edef\tmpB{#4}%
  \def\tmpC{\substring[#1]{#2}}
  \def\tmpD{\expandafter\tmpC\expandafter{\tmpA}}%
  \expandafter\tmpD\expandafter{\tmpB}%
}

\newcommand\stringpart[1]{
        input: #1\\
        string end is at position\ \whereisword{#1}{--}\\% this works
        \whereisword[q]{#1}{--}% Stores answer in \result
        \Substring{#1}{1}{\the\numexpr\theresult-1\relax}\\% works since expanded \result gives number
}

\begin{document}
\stringpart{this -- that}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am afraid it is way above my understanding of LaTeX, so I proceeded with the solution from the previous post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384421/140490
Thanks anyway!